# Apache camel SFTP handle "too many authentication failures"?

Tags: java, apache-camel, sftp

How to handle Apache camel SFTP "too many authentication failures"

When I tried with wrong password from Camel context, user is getting blocked from SFTP server. To avoid the issue I just want to poll only one time for connection establishment. if authentication fails, no further poll should happen from the camel.

Below is the SFTP endpoint config.

sftp://host/temp/?noop=true&eagerMaxMessagePerPoll=false
&MaxMessagesPerPoll=1& disconnect=true&delay=120000&streamDownload=true&stepWise=false&maximumReconnectAttemps=1&throwExceptionOnConnectionFailed=true&consumer.bridgeErrorHandler=true

Comment: I suspect you need to show your route configuration.

Comment: There is a `maximumReconnectAttempts`option that can be configured on a sftp endpoint

Comment: tried with MaximumReconnecAttempts

Comment: able catch the exception 
by the error handler. But before catching the exception itself connection attempts reaching the threshold and user is getting blocked

Comment: In the endpoint URL you pasted, the query parameter name is misspelled as **maximumReconnectAttemps**

Comment: Corrected @ChinHuang. Its typo mistake